# d3 Object [object Array] has no method 'tranisition'

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

```
 if (!d3.selectAll(".tooltip")[0].length) {
     var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
            .attr("class", "tooltip")
            .style("opacity", 0);
 }

function mouseover(d) {
            tooltip.tranisition()
            .duration(300)
            .style("opacity", 1);
}
```

If I change it to tooltip[0][0] it say HTMLDivElement has no method transition.  Wondering why it doesn't like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelt transition -- should be

```
tooltip.transition()
```

Comment: should I remove this question? What's the SO protocol here?  And thanks again.

Comment: I would probably remove it... It's unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: it says you have to remove the answer first.

Comment: Hmm, it says I can't delete the accepted answer. Might be easier to just leave it.

Comment: Would you mind looking at this? I don't know why the tooltips aren't showing up. var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0)
                .style("color", "black");

Comment: topBars.append("rect")
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    tooltip.transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .style("opacity", 1);

                    tooltip.html("Hello")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
                    .style("position", "absolute");
                });

Comment: is it because it is on top of an svg element? does that make a difference?

Comment: It's possible that the invisible tooltip is obscuring the SVG. Try `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: I already have that on the tooltip, i tried it on the svg and got nothing.. No worries, let me know if you get any more ideas

Comment: I was missing display: inline-block, in case you're curious